# Add to Cart not working only on Home Page in Magento

Tags: magento, cookies

All add to cart buttons on home page return "Your cart is empty". After working on it for some time I found that if I disable the Cache it works and then I narrowed it down to disabling Blocks HTML output. So it seems to be caching the form key but only on the home page, other cms pages work fine. Strange.

Here is the setting for "Session Cookie Management"

```
Cookie Lifetime:31536000
Cookie Path:
Cookie Domain:
Use HTTP Olny: Yes
Secure On Frontend: Yes
Cookie Restriction Mode: No
```

Here is the setting for "Session Validation Settings"

```
Validate REMOTE_ADDR:No
Validate HTTP_VIA: No
Validate HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: No
Validate HTTP_USER_AGENT: No
Use SID on Frontend: Yes
```

Here are the .htaccess rewrite rules

```
 Options All -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    redirect 301 /home https://www.domain.com
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]    
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^111\.11\.11\.11
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
    RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

I have this in app > etc > config.xml

```
<frontend>
  <secure_url>
     <all>/</all>
  </secure_url>
</frontend>
```

Only Magento! Any help would be appreciated.